# Oracle - Set Object to NonEditionable

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-19c

I am having an issue with *Editioning* in an Oracle 19c database. I have never heard of this feature before today, but I have found that somehow a number of objects in the database have had their `Editionable` property set to `'Y'`. We have never made use of this feature before, non of our users have *Editions* enabled, and the only edition in the database is the default `'ora$base'`. Even still, when I query `all_objects` and look at the `Edition_Name` field, I see that even those objects which have `Editionable` set to `'Y'` have an `Edition_Name` of `(null)`

Is there a way to modify these objects to reset their `Editionable` value to `'N'`?

This is preventing me from running some migration scripts as since the user does not have Editions enabled the `CREATE OR REPLACE` statements are trying to change the `Editionable` property of the objects back to `'N'` and thus we encounter the following error:

```
ORA-38824: A CREATE OR REPLACE command may not change the EDITIONABLE property of an existing object
```

So my question is, what command *may* change the `EDITIONABLE` property of an existing object?

Comment: Why? Editionable Objects (introduced in 11g, probably default for 19c) helps with low/no downtime application upgrades. What problem are you facing?

Comment: @MichaelKutz it's just not necessary, our application is a desktop application which is not used when users are not working, so we have natural downtime to run upgrades anyway. The problem is I am trying to run an upgrade but since the user does not have editions enabled, but some of the objects are set to be editionable, there is an error since the `CREATE OR REPLACE` statements are trying to replace with noneditionable objects as the user cannot create editionable objects.

Comment: What error? What `CREATE OR REPLACE` statement? This is possibly an XY Problem.

Comment: `DROP` object before run `CREATE OR REPLACE`